# In vanilla JavaScript, turn relative path + base URL into absolute URL

Tags: javascript, dom

In Ruby, it’s simple to do this, but in JavaScript, I’m not sure.

Given a starting page, such as `http://example.org/foo/bar`, I want to be able to take any link on the page, which can have any sort of `href` such as `/x.php`, `?p=3`, `y.html`, etc., and turn it into a fully qualified absolute URL, such as (in the last example) `http://example.org/foo/y.html`.

Is there any sort of simple way to do this? If it helps, we can assume these paths do live in an actual web page as actual `<a href>` elements.

Comment: What is your end goal here? You don't want to include base URL in your hyperlinks?

Comment: You could use the `<base>` tag if all URLs are meant to be impacted the same way. Otherwise, on each link you can manually set the `protocol` and `hostname` properties.

Comment: Hi @Cage — my goal involves lifting a section of HTML to be published elsewhere (as quoted rich text). The links should still function in their new home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [URL constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) takes a second, base argument, which does exactly what you want:

```js
const base = 'http://example.org/foo/bar';

[ '/x.php',
  '?p=3',
  'y.html'
].forEach(urlPart => {
  const url = new URL(urlPart, base);
  console.log(url.href);
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%}
```

```html
<script src="//rawgit.com/github/url-polyfill/0.5.6/url.js"></script>
```

The URL API works in [all major browsers except IE](http://caniuse.com/#feat=url). If you need to support IE, [there are polyfills available](https://github.com/github/url-polyfill). Node.js [also has it built in](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html) (`const { URL } = require('url');`).

Comment: Absolutely fantastic. The built-in API is exactly what I want to use, now that I know it exists. Luckily, this is for a bookmarklet and I don't care about IE 11 support.

Answer (score 2):

If your baseURL is equal to the current page, try this:

```
var getAbsoluteUrl = (function() {
    var a;

    return function(url) {
        if(!a) a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = url;

        return a.href;
    };
})();
```

Found here: https://davidwalsh.name/get-absolute-url

Tried it and it worked well for relative as well as absolute URLs (it makes them all absolute) - assuming your basePath is actually your own page.

Comment: This is fantastically useful to know as well. Thank you. I only wish I could mark two answers as accepted.

Comment: If you have a `<base>` element in your page, the baseURL will probably not be the current page. If you really want an url based on the current page, I would use `new URL(path, window.location.href)`

Answer (score 0):

Use this script (but test it first for the various cases, I just wrote it and wouldn't guarantee I haven't overlooked any case). Note that if the path of the URL specifies a directory and not a file, it always ends in a `/`, even though the browser might not show that.

```
var getAbsoluteURL = function (url, href) {
    var path = url.split(/[#?]/)[0];
    var basePath = path.slice(0, path.lastIndexOf('/'));
    var domain = url.split('/').slice(0,3).join('/');
    var protocol = url.split('/')[0];

    switch (href.charAt(0)) {
        case '/':
        {
            if (href.length > 1 && href.charAt(1) == '/')
                return protocol + href;
            else
                return domain + href;
        }
        case '#':
        case '?':
            return path + href;
        default:
            return basePath + '/' + href;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your efforts are sincerely appreciated! I am going to let the browser do the heavy lifting, though, for exactly the reason that I don't want to accidentally miss a case.